# Change href when anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question about how I can dynamically change a `href=""` in a button.

The jsfiddle below shows a button fixed at the bottom of the viewport starting at the landing page:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6mA/3/

The html of the button is like so:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#first" class="" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; opacity: 1;">
        <img src="img/down.png" alt="down">
    </a>
</div>
```

When it is clicked I want it to scroll to the next section and change the href="" to the following section of the page. So, when it is first clicked, the href will change to #second. It would obviously also need to change when the user manually scrolls past a section.

This is for a single page website. How would I go about such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fullPage.js plugin to achieve what you want. Maybe it is faster than coding it from cero :)

- [Demo fullPaje.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Page](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change its value

```
$(".button").on('click', function(){
    $('.button').find('a').prop('href', '#services');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6mA/11/)

Comment: I just updated the link as they were broken before. I have tried your new solution but am having complications still. Thanks [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm6mA/15/) @Satpal

Comment: @DizzyChamp, What complication dear?

Comment: Do i add another prop call so that it changes ,when I get to the #first section, to #second...? @Satpal

Answer (score 1):

I am not used to jquery. Here is a pure javascript solution. It surely changes the hash value.

```
<body>

    <div id="sections">

        <section id="s100">asdfasd</section>
        <section id="s101"></section>
        <section id="s102"></section>
        <section id="s103"></section>
        <section id="s104">asdfasdasdfsdf</section>
        <section id="s105"></section>

    </div>

    <div class="nav-bar">

        <a id="next-button" class="button" href="#s100">Next</a>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var sections = document.getElementById("sections");

        var nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');

        sections.onscroll = function (evt) {

        }


        var counter = 100;
        var limit = 105;

        // closure
        nextButton.onmouseup = function (evt) {

            var incCounter = function () {
                // add your custom conditions here

                if(counter <= limit)
                    return counter++;
                return 0;
            };

            var c = incCounter();
            if(c != 0)
                this.setAttribute('href', "#s" + c);
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #sections {
            height: 50%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .nav-bar {
            margin: 30px 20px;
        }

        .button {
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 120%;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small jQuery plugin for that, just pushed it to GitHub. https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/scrollstack

What you basically want to do is calling

`$('.button').scrollstack({stack: ['#first', '#second', ... ]});`

You dont even need the link when you call it on the button. So check it out and let me know if it works for you. ;)

Here you can try it and read more: http://ferdinandtorggler.github.io/scrollstack/

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, could you please tell me what browser you are using? For me it works in Chrome and Firefox, but I will definitely try to fix this asap :)

Comment: Ok, it should be fixed now :)